# Get value from consent input on Gravity Forms

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I’m working with this customized form that has text, e-mail, checkbox and the consent fields. But I’m having some trouble on getting the right values from the **consent field** to send it to the admin panel. The other ones works really fine and the fields value are sent without any trouble.

Only including the shortcode of the Gravity form on a default page on Wordpress that has a consent field, a single "checkbox" is shown to me and it sends three values, which:

- 1st: I think it's a true or false field, cause when I press send on the form without checbing the field it doesn't show up on the Network tab;
- 2nd: is the label of the consent field
- 3rd: is the form id

Here is how on the Network tab the information is sent:

[image]

So, in my code, I set it up like this:

```
this.form.on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const dataValues = { input_values: {} };

    // Extract field values
    this.fields.each((index, element) => {
        let field = $(element);

        switch (field.attr('type')) {
            // Checkbox
            case 'checkbox':
                if (field.prop('checked')) {
                    dataValues.input_values[field.attr('name').replace(/\./g, '_')] = field.val();
                }
                break;

            case 'consent':
                dataValues.input_values[field.attr('name').concat('_1')] = '1';
                dataValues.input_values[field.attr('name').concat('_2')] = field.val();
                dataValues.input_values[field.attr('name').concat('_3')] = this.form.attr('data-form-id');
                break;

            // Email, Select, Text
            default:
                dataValues.input_values[field.attr('name')] = field.val();
                break;
        }
    });

    //axios
});
```

I just think that the consent field on this switch is missing something, or is sent in a different way as the others. Like the checkbox field that it's in my code, I needed to replace the dot for the underscore so that the value is sent. But I've already tried that and it didn't work.

This is the response that I get on my custom Gravity form:
[image]